# My ListBox need three DataTemplate,How to get correct DataTemplate?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

there are three category in my ListBox. I need display three category in the ListBox. So , I must define three DataTemplate for ListBox, but How to make category and DataTemplate is corresponding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the datatemplate selector class in silverlight. more info visit

http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/09/28/datatemplateselector-in-silverlight.aspx